# Java basics what thread 1 writes can be read in thread 2 without writing a volatile variable and why

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code, in writer thread, there is no `volatile` variable write operation, like `flag =` , but reader thread reads `list.set(0, 1)`. In my mind, writer thread make variable `list` seeable in the other thread, only if it is written to main memory, for example, by using a `volatile` write operation. While in the following code, there is no such operation in writer thread, what makes reader thread read value change in list? JDK 8.

Moreover, I found that `System.out.print` also makes `list` change seeable in reader threat. If `volatile` removed from variable `flag` or no `System.out.print`, then reader threat could not see `list` change. (It seems to be this)

```
    private static List<Integer> list;
    private static volatile boolean flag;
    static {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
        list.add(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        new Thread(()->{ // writer thread
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.set(0,1);

            System.out.println("set 1");
        }).start();
        new Thread(()->{ // reader thread

            while (list.get(0) == 0){
                // System.out.println("");
                boolean v = flag;
            }
            System.out.println("end");
            latch.countDown();

        }).start();
        latch.await();
    }
```

Comment: Volatile gives you a *guarantee* but lack of a guarantee doesn't mean it won't happen. Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Comment: @Michael without `volatile` then it for sure wont happen.

Comment: No. Lack of volatile doesn't mean anything will happen "for sure". It may work or may not.

Comment: writing code needs a bit more than *may work or may not*, like write volatile sync and flush, read volatile reload.

Comment: @Michael *I never said...*, by reading your comment, I don't know what should I think. I still don't understand why with and without volatile that code have difference.

Comment: Volatile -> guaranteed visibility of writes between threads. No volatile -> **no guarantee** of visibility. Writes *may still be visible anyway*. Your question was "*what makes reader thread read value change in list*"? My explanation should answer that.

Comment: Re, "without volatile then it for sure wont happen." The Java Language Specification, does not say that thread B will never see what thread A wrote if there is no synchronization between them. It only says that there is no guarantee _if or when_ thread B will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing to main memory is a [fallacy](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-reorderings-and-commit). This is not how modern CPU's work and hence a broken mental model.

Even with the flag being volatile, you do not have a happens-before edge between writing the list and reading the list and hence your code has a data race and is officially broken.

Comment: `while` in `reader` makes it a logical happens-before

Comment: That is not the meaning of happens-before. If A happens-before B, then B is guaranteed to see all the memory effects till and including A.

Comment: writing `list` once, and `while` waits for its (`list`) change. That data race won't last long. if morden CPU does not use main memory, what does it use? and in this case, what is the sensible meaning (maybe a new theory) behind CPU memory and `volatile`?

Comment: I would suggest diving into the JMM first.

Comment: Data races do not need to be resolved over time. It could be that the compiler transforms the code in such a way that behavior changes permanently.

Comment: @Tiina, The memory systems of different computers can work in different ways, but a well written Java program should behave in the same way on any of them. The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) defines what "well written" means for a Java program, and it tells you what to expect when the program is well written. It does not, and it _cannot_ tell you what to expect from a program that is _not_ well written. Your program is not well written because of what pveentjer said.

Comment: @Tiina please read the following article about happening-before vs happens-before. https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/